# Batch file gives "the system cannot find the file specified" but commands run fine in cmd

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, batch

I'm trying to run a simple batch file:

```
@echo off      <-- don't print this line or any of the preceeding lines to the console window.
pushd "K:\"    <-- in the quoted directory
for %%j in (*) <-- for every file in the directory
do
if %%~zj       <-- if the size of the file
lss 37000      <-- is less than 37k
del %%j        <-- delete the file
popd           <-- go back to original directory.
```

I start getting an error at the `@echo off` and `pushd`, but if I try `pushd` in `cmd.exe` it runs just fine. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Any ideas?

Comment: **What** error do you start getting?

Comment: At `@echo off` and `pushd`. i get " the system cannot find the file specified" , when it gets to the loop, it closes the cmd window..

Comment: I got it, it was the comments at the side that I had left in were causing the hiccup

Answer (score 8):

This happens when you use a program to start your batch file and the batch file isn't calling `cmd.exe /c` first. There's no `pushd.exe`, it's a built-in command under `cmd.exe`. But when your program calls your batch file, it's starting it directly - there's no `cmd.exe`. (Yes, this is weird.)

The solution: Wherever you're running this from, precede it with `cmd.exe /c`

So if you're running `deletelittlefiles.bat` change it to `cmd.exe /c deletelittlefiles.bat`.

Source: I'm a lab manager for a software testing team and our test harness can but doesn't have to run things without starting them under `cmd.exe`.